# How to access WP header from Appearance > Header using WP Rest api (React)

Tags: rest-api, headless, react

Need to use the WordPress Header Section in react js. No plugin is used for plugin it is by default.

Comment: there is no REST API endpoint for this you'd have to build one. Note that modern WP themes don't use that functionality for headers though, they use the site editor

Comment: Please tell me , can we do like If we create header using acf?

Comment: you'd have to ask about ACF fields in an ACF community, questions about 3rd party plugins/themes are offtopic here. Note that creating a new REST API endpoint from scratch is not that hard, what you want could probably be done in less than 10 lines of code

Comment: Okay Thanks....